# Get and Set ("private") in C disadvantages?

Tags: c, private

I wanted to make a struct in C that its data couldn't be accessed by anyone directly, just through gets and sets like in Object Oriented. My solution was something like:

Point.h

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

typedef struct point Point;

Point *CreatePoint(int x, int y);

int Point_GetX(Point *point);
void Point_SetX(Point *point, int x);

int Point_GetY(Point *point);
void Point_SetY(Point *point, int y);

void DeletePoint(Point **p);

#endif /* POINT_H */
```

Point.c

```
#include "Point.h"

struct point{
    int x, y;
};

Point *CreatePoint(int x, int y){
    Point *p = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;

    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;

    return p;
}

int Point_GetX(Point *point){
    return point->x;
}
void Point_SetX(Point *point, int x){
    point->x = x;
}
int Point_GetY(Point *point){
    return point->y;
}
void Point_SetY(Point *point, int y){
    point->y = y;
}

void DeletePoint(Point **p){
    if (*p != NULL){
        free(*p);
        *p = NULL;
    }
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Point.h"

int main(){
    Point *p = CreatePoint(2, 6);
    if (p == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    /*
    p->x = 4;               "error: dereferencing pointer
    p->y = 9;               to incomplete type"
    */
    Point_SetX(p, 4);
    Point_SetY(p, 9);

    printf("POINT(%d,%d)", Point_GetX(p), Point_GetY(p));

    DeletePoint(&p);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Of course I'd never to all this just to a simple Point, but that's the idea. I want to know what could go wrong by doing this, whether I should be doing this or not, and if it's OK to do this, if it's not a smart approach (and I should just go for c++ xD).
The reason of this is that I'm doing a little project but I may change some data structures and algorithms later on, so if I do this, I just need to change the Point.c in this case, and not every single place I'd do

```
point->x = new_x
```

for example.

Basically, am I trying to do what c++ do? Or it's OK to do this in C? Or not, there's a disadvantage? Or this is simply not what C was meant to be? haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My solution was something like [this]

This is the classic solution in C for information hiding. The only missing thing is `DestroyPoint`, a function to deallocate the point structure which you allocate with `malloc`.

> I want to know what could go wrong by doing this, whether I should be doing this or not, and if it's OK to do this.

It is a safe approach, as long as you are OK with its disadvantage, which is described below.

> [is there] a disadvantage?

Yes, there is: this approach is limited to dynamic allocation of data structures the internals of which you hide. You cannot do this:

```
Point p; // This fails, because `Point` is a forward declaration.
int x = Point_GetX(&p);
```

Similarly, arrays of `Point`s are off-limit; embedding of `Point`s in other `struct`s is not possible as well.

> Am I trying to do what C++ does?

Not really. Your approach is similar to Objective-C, because C++ does not have a limitation of allocating objects only in the dynamic store, while Objective-C does. This limitation does not seem to create much problems for Objective-C programmers, though.

Comment: Didn't know this was common, I just remembered someone saying it some time ago. And completely forgot about free, shame on me xD. Anyways, this answer made me think: overall, is Objective-C used by many programmers? I never knew someone who used Objective-C besides those who developed for iOS before Swift. Is it a good language to work on?

Comment: @WalrusNine iOS has definitely given Objective-C a life after a near death. It's an OK language, but the code is not as terse as that in more modern languages, e.g. Swift. At this point the language remains relevant, because Swift remains in flux, so most commercial iOS development is still done in Objective-C.

Comment: @WalrusNine:  It's so common it happens at the major OS libc level:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0477/6j9r2e2b9/index.html   "The FILE structure has a long history, and a few applications have looked inside the structure to glean additional information about the state of the stream. Because the 64-bit version of the structure is now opaque, a new family of routines has been added to both 32-bit libc and 64-bit libc to allow the same state to be examined without depending on implementation internals. See, for example, __fbufsize(3C)"

Answer (score 1):

The kind of encapsulation strategy you describe is used relatively frequently in C libraries.  It is perfectly fine.

Do note, however, that it is encapsulation by *convention*, not enforced by the language itself, as access to `private` members is enforced in C++.  In C, although *you* don't provide a complete declaration of `struct point`, any client code could do so, enabling it to access instances' members.

Answer (score 1):

how many instances of a point struct are needed?

just one or several?

in any case, the function:CreatePoint() gaves away the farm as it gave the point data to the world.

The code needs to hide the actual content of point (and its' fields) from the world.

then ONLY the accessor functions can access point.

If there needs to be multiple instances of point,

then the CreatePoint() returns some integer that can be used in other calls to the accessor functions to select the right point.

the CreatePoint function would perform something like a malloc() to obtain room for a new point.

There probably should be a function to destroy a point (mark it destroyed in a table of points?)

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("POINT(%d,%d)", Point_GetX(&p), Point_GetY(&p));
```

should be:

```
printf("POINT(%d,%d)", Point_GetX(p), Point_GetY(p));
```